# WCF: DataContractAttribute and Namespace

Tags: wcf

When I auto-generate my client classes I get these attributes.

```
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(), _
 System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0"), _
 System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name:="FeedStatusReport", [Namespace]:="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/OfferingSystem"), _
 System.SerializableAttribute()>
```

On the server side, how do I change the namespace that the client sees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this with your ServiceContract:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://someNameSpaceGoesHere/")]
public interface ISomeService
{
...
}
```

Comment: Close. You also need to put a DataContractAttribute on all non-primative types.

Comment: @Jonathon Allen - Are you sure that is right? Primative types don't need DataContractAttribute? Do you have any references? Thanks.